# Change particular Edittext box locale to English if App locale is arabic

Tags: android, android-edittext, locale, arabic

I am working on a application which is having Arabic and English language like user can switch to any language between these two,My problem comes when i change my language to Arabic because i try to put any number in EditText view it automatically converts it into Arabic font.

I want to show english number font even when the language is set to arabic in edittext view.

**This is my code which i used to change locale in my code :--**

```
public class LocaleHelper {

    private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

    public static void onCreate(Context context) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static void onCreate(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
        setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
        return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    }

    public static void setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        persist(context, language);
        updateResources(context, language);
    }

    private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
    }

    private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
        editor.apply();
    }

    private static void updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;

        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your keyboard Arabic too?

Comment: No my keyboard is English

Comment: Can I see exactly where did you change the locale to Arabic (code) ?

Comment: Please check above i have added the code for changing locale to arabic.

Comment: When do you get Arabic number ? While typing English number and then it is showing in Arabic in editText ? Or you are getting English number but when you try to get editText value you are getting Arabic value? What is the situation ?

Comment: When i am typing in edit text box and my app locale set to arabic then it gives me arabic numbers in edittext box...i want edit text box to show me only english numbers regardless to the arabic locale

Comment: @VarunJain - have you found any solution for this. I am also facing the same issue. But I need all editbox which is having number input should display the number in english only. Please let me know if you have any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using **StringFormat** you can set different language than the application language.
In my scenario I have to set Hindi as an application language but English for EditText, see below.

```
val lengthAConverted = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,"%.2f", lengthA.toFloat())
dmh_s2_length_a_edit_text.text = lengthAConverted
```